# Updating toolchain MinGw from gcc 4.7 to gcc 5.3 causes linking problems

Tags: gcc, cmake, clion, toolchain

I am using Clion version 2017.1 (updated recently) with Cmake 3.7 on windows7 with MinGw and compiler gcc 5.3.

Recently I updated the compiler from 4.7 to 5.3, and I changed it in the settings > toolchain windows in Clion. Cmake finds all compilers and everything is fine. However, when I build the program with this new toolchain, it complains of "undefined reference" error which is related to linking libraries. I didn't need to change my CMakeLists file because everything is the same. The interesting part is when I change the toolchain to the old version, the program builds without any problem.

Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? I attached two images with two different toolchains. One is successful another one is not.

Thanks for your help.

[image: susccessfull build with old gcc 4.7]

[image: unsusccessful build with new gcc 5.3]

Comment: Common C++ incompatibiliby problem: Libraries built with gcc 4.7 cannot be linked into executable built with gcc 5.3. You need both libraries and executable to be built with the **same** compiler.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I rebuild my library with 5.3, and tried it with DevCpp, it compiles my code with new compiler but Clion and Cmake don't compile it. I thought maybe I should update my Clion and Cmake with new compiler, I upgraded to Clion 2017.1 with bundled Cmake, but the problem remains.